# Setting black for one line - There are more web links on the line

Tags: html, colors, hyperlink

I'm trying to set black for one line. There are more web links on the line. But the link is still blue. Thanks for the help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Titulek stránky</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2 style="color:black;"><a href="https://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a> <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></h2>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is a **default style** from `<a>` tag, which it hides the set style from `<h2>`. There are 2 ways (not only 2) to resolve the problem.

- Way 1: by adding a `<style>` tag and put your styles inside it.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Titulek stránky</title>
        <style>
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2><a href="https://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a> <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

- Way 2 (not recommended because it looks not really tidy): add styles to each `<a>` tag.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Titulek stránky</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">YouTube</a>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">Google</a>
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope helped.

Comment: @Pro525 If my answer answered correctly your question, you can give me a "tick" to mark the best answer for you. That will be very helpful for both of us. Thank you.